# Custom form headers based on controls, display through tabbing

Tags: database, ms-access

I have two problems with my form in Access that has tabs (tab control). I need my form to display the full name and date of birth as a header updating as I go through records (see screenshot below). This information exists in my first tab, Personal but is linked to my other tabs, Medical and Reinsurance through the Customer ID.

Problem #1: I can get the Full Name to display at the top (although it asks for a parameter value when I open the form) and change as I click through records but I cannot get the Date of Birth to work. I tried using the same exact process as full name but for some reason, this will not work for the date of birth. I created the full name with the following in the Control Source:

`=[Customers-Personal1].[Form]![First Name] & " " & [Customers-Personal1].[Form]![Last Name]`

and I tried the following in the control source for Date of Birth which works for the first record only:

`=[Customers-Personal1].[Form]![Date of Birth]`

I have tried adding a textbox and adding the control source. I also tried adding the DOB as an existing field but that did not work either. Please help.

***UPDATE*** I have solved problem # 1******. The formula works as is, I just had an extra space in my field.

Problem #2: I cannot get either of these headers to work in my other tabs, Medical and Reinsurance which are linked via customer ID. I realize I need to add that into the control source but am not sure how to do so. Maybe these need to be queries? Or do they need to be headers within each tab?

Any help provided is greatly appreciated. I am learning as I go and have very little experience with Access.

****UPDATE**
Problem #3
Is there a way to get the same record to display in all three tabs...so that if I click to my second record in the Personal tab, I will see the details for the second record in the Medical and Reinsurance tabs? Does have to do with the event property?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHQbH.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'tabs' - a Tab control or a Navigation form? Exactly where do you want this info to display - in textbox in form header section? You are pulling values from subform record onto main form?

Comment: @June7, Tab control (see screenshot). I want it displayed at the top of the form, preferably in the header section. I created 3 forms, Personal, Medical and Reinsurance and then dropped them into each tab. First name, last name and date of birth are only fields on the Personal tab so I was thinking maybe I needed to add them to each tab but only make them visible on the Personal tab.

Comment: What are relationships? These three subforms pull data from same data source? Why use subforms? Bind main form to the data source and put textboxes directly on pages of the Tab control. If hese are 3 related data sources - Personal is 'master' and the others are 'dependent' - bind main form to Personal and put controls directly on page of Tab control. Set Master/Child Properties links. Unless you want to also show Personal as datasheet view then review https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp